# Reshape dataframe with numeric and character variables

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

probabily it is refusee. 
I want to transpose a data frame that has both numeric and character columns. I have some lines where the id is repeated 2 or even more times. I would like to have a final dataframe where I have this data in one line.
I thought about using both the data.table and reshape2 library (they have similar functions) but I can't find the right combination to do what I want and I'm going crazy. Could someone give me some help?
Here a modified example of my database

```
example_data <-data.frame(cod=c(20,20,20,20,20,20,20,40,80,80,80,80,80,240), 
                      id=c(44,68,137,150,186,236,289,236,44,150,155,236,68,289),
                      textVar=c('aaaa','aaaa','aaaa bbbb','aaaa','cccc','cccc','cccc bbb','dddd','dddd cccc','dddd','ffff','ffff gggg','ffff','hhhh'),
                      ww=c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,45,118,118,118,118,118,118))
```

If for example consider the column with id=44 my output is like this:

```
exampleRow <-data.frame(cod_1=c(20),id=c(44),textVar_1=c('aaaa'),ww_1=c(4),cod_2=c(80),id=c(44),textVar_2=c('dddd cccc'),ww_2=c(118))
```

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Comment: Not clear without expected output.  May be `library(data.table);dcast(setDT(example_data), id ~ cod, value.var = c('textVar', 'ww'))`

Comment: Could you add the expected output?

Comment: I update the question

Comment: I think I've found solution of problem with this command line
dcast(setDT(example_data), id ~ rowid(id), value.var = c('cod','textVar','ww'))